# Laravel 5.0 Pagination render() method return HTML text

Tags: php, laravel, pagination, laravel-pagination

I have a controller which send some product to the view. In the controller I paginated the data using

```
...
// Controller code

Product::paginate(1) // because I only have 2 dummy data, 1 product per page
return view('product.index', compact('product'));

...
```

then in my product.index view I have the following code:

```
    <!-- Pagination link -->
    [[ $products->render() ]]
    <!-- End Paginatin link -->
```

The code works, but it return the HTML without being rendered by the browser as element. The resulting output is like below

```
<ul class="pagination"><li class="disabled"><span>«</span></li> <li class="acti![enter image description here][2]ve"><span>1</span></li><li><a href="http://localhost:3000/paketsoal/public/dashboard/my-product/?page=2">2</a></li> <li><a href="http://localhost:3000/paketsoal/public/dashboard/my-product/?page=2" rel="next">»</a></li></ul>
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use unescaped block `{!! !!}`:

```
{!! $products->render() !!}
```

Comment: Thank you for your super fast response. It works! is there any laravel documentation on that topic?

Comment: Sure, here http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/pagination you can find example with ``<?php echo $users->render(); ?>`` which is equals to ``{!! $users->render() !!}``

Comment: Oh, I thought echo was equal to {{ $users->render() }}

Comment: in L4 it was, in L5 it's not, read more: http://laravel.com/docs/master/upgrade#upgrade-5.0 in section "Blade Tag Changes"

Comment: Oh, I missed that one. Very well, it's clear now. Thank a lot @limonte!!